# Working with Simple JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I Created my `<form>` using `HtmL` now I need to know how to create a function that I can return a value to fill my `Input type="text"`.

E.g:  **UPDATE**

```
  <html>
<head>
<title>Aula 21.03.2013 </title>
<script>
    function CalculaNota()
    {
        var p1 = document.getElementById("txtp1").value;
        var p2 = document.getElementById("txtp2").value;        

        return p1;
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fieldset" style="border: 2px solid pink; width: 250px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding: 10px;" >
    <form name="formulario" action="" method="post">
        P1<br>
        <input type="text" id="txtp1" /><br>
        P2<br>
        <input type="text" id="txtp2" /><br>

        <input type="submit" value="CALCULAR"  OnClick="CalculaNota()"/> 
        <br><br>

        NOTA FINAL<br>
        <input type="text" id="txtnota_final"/>
    </form>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I Click on the button, nothing happens !

Comment: Just add return NF or document.findElementById('txtp2').value = NF;

Comment: @Damian0o I didnt get you I'm sorry, what would be exactly the code to return the value and to sign it to the textbox ? Thanks

Comment: It is basics. You should first do some tutorial like w3shools or many in the internet then ask questions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  function CalculaNota()
    {
        var p1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtp1").value);
        //You were re-assigning p1 here, I've changed it to p2
        var p2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtp2").value);     
        var NF = ((p1 + (2 * p2)) / 3);

        document.getElementById("txtnota_final").value = NF;
    }
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the `value` property returns a string, not a number; you might want to ensure that you're working with valid numbers before using them in math, to avoid `NaN` situations.

Comment: This is the answer. You also probably want to modify your button declaration to `<input type="button" id="bt_calcular" value="CALCULAR" onclick="CalculaNota()" />`

Comment: @DavidThomas well spotted cheers, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('bt_calcular').onclick = function ()
    {
        var p1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtp1").value);
        var p2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtp2").value);        
        var NF = ((p1 + (2 * p2)) / 3);
        document.getElementById('txtnota_final').value = NF;
    }
</script>
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8EkMf/1

Also you should close your `form` tag before the last `div`

you are not closing your script tag

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

And you dont need jquery for this.. you are using vanila javascript

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro edited code. try now..

Comment: I guess i'm doing something else wrong... It does not even fire a simple `alert("djjsa");` ;\

Comment: fire up your console and see if you have any errors

Comment: I'm using NotePad++ and testing on the browser x.x

Comment: if you open your page in chrome browser then just hit `f12` and select "console" or you can use firebug in firefox.

Comment: the value is been signed to my `txtnota_final` but it appears and vanish very fast... What could it be ?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro updated the answer.. Also use the function from my updated answer.. you are calling the function on page load when there is no value for textp1 and textp2.. hence it will return empty.

Comment: I'm not using Jquery, I just messed up the two projects that is open here... Sorry, now the value on the textbox appears and desappear really fast, again ! Updated...